# linux - get kernel config without having /proc/config.gz

Tags: linux

I want to get the kernel defconfig of a Android Mediatek device with closed kernel source with android nougat. (for kernel bringup)

I tried looking for /proc/config.gz it does not exist. Likely cause the kernel was built with `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC` off.

I tried using https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/scripts/extract-ikconfig on zImage. No luck. Probably because `CONFIG_IKCONFIG` was off, since google does not require that for anything lower than android oreo.

Are there any other ways to get the config or is this it? I didn't find any other way so decided to ask here.

Comment: If you own the device you can request the source from MediaTek.  It would be a copyright violation to ship Linux on the device without providing the source.

Comment: @stark mediatek is not the manufacturer. micromax is just the SoC is mtk. and yes it doesnt ship with kernel source. and since micromax is small enough they dont even care about GPLv2

Comment: All that matters is who distributes it.  They have to provide source.

Comment: i know. but small chineese companies dont really care about GPL

Comment: So why are you buying pirated software?

Comment: @stark lol had a good laugh

Comment: Have you tried googling for _micromax <device> github_?

Comment: @ninjalj ofc i did. all i found was petitions for micromax to release their sources